# Twitter feed not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-feed

I have browsed the web trying to find a solution to this problem, many people have suggested disabling avast plugin, add blocker within chrome extensions yet none of these worked.

the url is https://careers.telstra.com/ you will see half way down next to the facebook feed the twitter feed is empty when using chrome, when I view this in IE, FireFox it displays as I would expect.

I've checked the console log in Firefox  and I receive no errors, when I go to chrome on the other hand I see the following:

[image]

I personally do not think these are related it any way but I thought I would provide as much information as possible to try and get this fixed.

*update* Turns out the errors are related to google-cast-sdk instead of silently dumping the errors they have decided to dump them straight in to the console. [Read more about it here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309)

I've checked and made sure I'm referencing the correct twitter widget.

We build it as follows as pass it to the page

```
 sb.Append("<div class=\"twitterWidget\"><a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"//twitter.com/telstracareers\" data-widget-id=\"345026269295038465\" data-chrome=\"nofooter noscrollbar transparent\" data-tweet-limit=\"3\">Tweets by @telstracareers</a></div>");
```

The website runs under https, I have tried the following:

```
href=\"https://twitter.com/telstracareers\"
href=\"//twitter.com/telstracareers\"
```

Still have no luck, I'm not sure what else I could try any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The widgets typically require a script tag as well as the given html. Are you including that, too? Are you also sure that the widget has been saved?

Comment: @sesamechicken I'm including everything, it works fine on all other browsers just not Chrome for some daft reason...

Comment: Does it work in Chrome in incognito mode (i.e. when browser extensions are disabled)?

Comment: @samgak I've tried that, disabled all extensions, cleared cache the lot but yet it doesn't seem to show

Comment: @ScottAtkinson other browsers may be more forgiving, but try loading jQuery over https - you have a few errors on that page in Chrome 43.0.2357.18

Comment: @sesamechicken correct I've seen the errors but from what I've read online its from a google-cast-sdk

Comment: There are more errors than just the extension ones. Look again.

Comment: @sesamechicken there the only errors I see, the picture I have attached in my question are the ones I see.

Comment: jQuery does not load - needs to be https like the rest of the page - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Remento hey where are you seeing that on the page? I've just right clicked viewed source and can't see it anywhere?

Comment: @Remento found that, now fixed it and still the problem persists....

Comment: Is this how the other feeds are brought in? I tried your code using jQuery to append() (I assume you're using a string builder in vb.net or something), and it works. Have you considered this approach? The iframe that is created in that area is empty.

Comment: @sesamechicken yes all feeds are brought in the same way, which is why I find this very strange, all other browsers its fine. We have a front end guy looking at it now so I'm waiting to hear back from him, will update accordingly